# Android Studio, Work with Google Drive (Do nothing)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-android-api

I want to upload files and download files from google drive
I follow this guide: 
https://github.com/googlearchive/drive-android-quickstart

I just do copy past and run the app, I got dialog box with request login to google account, I login and then nothing!!!
According to the guide after chose the account it should open another dialog box with title "Upload to Drive", But nothing.

I am using this two:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
```

I Think that I need to put somewhere the API KEY in my project, But I do not know where.
Please Some help

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructional video [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/), you're supposed to take a picture first.